# How to add a second 'place order' button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, hooks, woocommerce-offtopic

My client would like two 'Place order' buttons on his checkout page (http://www.jobgrandprix.fr/checkout/?set-cart-qty_2652=1).

By default, the 'Commander' (his site is in French) button is at the bottom of the page. I'm trying to add a second one in the right hand column at the top of the page.

I think form-checkout.php is what I need to modify. I think I need to add it where the shipping column usually is (not used here because it is a virtual product).

If anyone has any pointers I'd be really grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to add it within the checkout form, just add a similar submit button, but inside the checkout form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place Order Button can't go out of the `<form></form>` element. What you can do is you can duplicate the button within the  element but at the top. like this:

[image]

**For this:**

Withing you child theme make a folder `woocommerce` and inside that `checkout`.

Now go to `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\checkout` and copy `form-checkout.php` file and paste that into `MY_CHILD_THEME\woocommerce\checkout` folder and edit it.

**WHY ABOVE STEP?**
So that you won't edit the core woocommerce files and the update will be lost when this plugin updates in future. The above structure overrides the core template file.

**OK NOW EDIT** form-checkout.php

Below

`<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout" action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>">`

Add the Button Code and it should look like this.

```
<form name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout"
action="<?php echo esc_url( $get_checkout_url ); ?>">

<div class="form-row place-order">

  <noscript>Since your browser does not support JavaScript, or it is disabled,
    please ensure you click the &amp;lt;em&amp;gt;Update Totals&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;
    button before placing your order. You may be charged more than the amount
    stated above if you fail to do so.&amp;lt;br/&amp;gt;&amp;lt;input type="submit"
    class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_update_totals"
    value="Update totals" /&amp;gt;</noscript>

    <input
    type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce"
    value="c82a4af261"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer"
    value="/woocommerce2/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" />

    <input
    type="submit" class="button alt" name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order"
    id="place_order" value="Place order" data-value="Place order" />

  </div>

  <?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>
```

Save it and Bingo. You can do some CSS and align the button to the right side of the form element. But remember it can't go out of `<form></form>` element.

Comment: Sudeep.... you are a LEGEND!!!!! :)

Comment: My pleasure :) You can edit the code as per the requirement and do the desired CSS to change the look.